# Downvoting accepted answers without comment

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, down-votes

One person has downvoted my answer yesterday with a comment saying `answer contain bad advice`. Although that answer was accepted by OP and upvoted by one user also. But the user which has given an answer also which is not accepted by OP has downvoted and commented the answer contains a bad advice. even If I asked what bad advice my answer contains so that I can correct my answer and learn something. He did not replied though his answer didn't get any upvote. So what can I do in this case.

Comment: "now he is downvoting my every answer without leaving any comment" You've had two answers downvoted in the last day. There's no need to overreact like this.

Comment: I believe that it shouldn't make a difference if the answer is accepted or not: accepted just means that it satisfied the OP. After that, there's tonnes of material on all meta sites about downvoting without comments. Also, you loose only 2 reputation on downvotes, but you gain 15 for an 'accept'. If at all, you can discuss the specific incident on the meta of the site where this happened. Please don't just rant.

Comment: @NathanTuggy But for me two downvotes also matters without any reason. Why a single downvote if there is no reason, do you find `this answer contains a bad advice` is even a proper comment.

Comment: @Chair downvote I can handle its ok but there should be reason so that I can learn from my mistakes. Also If you downvote your tag bage reputation goes down by one point. I just want a comment to be fair so that I can learn from my mistakes. There been a downvote before by some but they gave a proper reason and it helped me to learn more so I am thankful to them but this is wrong. don't you think

Comment: @Himanshu If they left a meaningless comment like "bad advice", you can ask them to be more specific in another comment... And after that, look at this meta post: [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) and the linked/related questions.

Comment: @Himanshu: Just because someone did not explain their reasoning does not mean they didn't have any, although it would certainly be much better if they did explain. But your second downvoted post may well have been downvoted by someone else.

Comment: @Chair thanks for help I did the same first I have come here after trying everything but the person never commented again also his answer deserved a downvote because he just showing an error in the question which he can do by editing the question. But I can't downvote because he has more reputation also no one downvotes because of his reputation.

Comment: "But I can't downvote because he has more reputation" Whether you can downvote or not solely depends on *your* reputation, not another user's.

Comment: @NathanTuggy yes I checked thanks I was just downvoted before too there are some who just downvote without any reason but when you read there answers they should be downvoted too for the same reason. So I can't say like your answer also contains same mistake but because they have more repo no one downvote them

Comment: "there are some who just downvote without any reason but when you read there answers they should be downvoted too for the same reason" What makes you so sure you know who actually downvoted? Down- and upvotes are still anonymous.

Comment: @AnneDaunted I don't wants to downvote because someone has put their effort and if that answer conatins some important thing even if it is not relevant to answer I never downvote. But I guarantee that If I give that answer the same answer /i surely be downvoted. Now you know this is not good

Comment: @AnneDaunted because someone given a comment laughing comment `this answer contains bad advice` what do you think is this can be the reason for downvote and if it contains a bad advice then be clear so that I can also learn from my mistakes. I always happy to learn. I have been downvoted on my answers before but I learn from my mistakes because some guys are really good and their comments helped me to learn what mistakes I have done

Comment: thanks all for your time.

Comment: "But I can't downvote because he has more reputation also no one downvotes because of his reputation." That's not a thing. Even [Jon Skeet gets downvotes (his most recent one being a mere two days ago, in fact)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation). Some random 80k user? Pfft. [They got downvoted twice in the last 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221700/peterso?tab=reputation). You have more than 125 rep. Therefore you can downvote. That's all there is to it. None of this "has more rep" nonsense. That's not how the site works.

Comment: @NathanTuggy thanks for your information. I don't wants to downvote anyone I am here to learn and help people. Thanks all for your time.

Comment: @Himanshu Actually, you're encouraged to downvote stuff which you know is inaccurate (or has similar significant flaw), irrespective of the effort put in. You're helping future readers by downvoting bad content: you're signalling that the particular post shouldn't be considered seriously. Downvotes should not be taken personally, and you shouldn't think that anybody else takes them as personal insults either. You don't downvote a person. You downvote a post.

Comment: @Chair yes I get it but I am saying if there is post which requires downvote I just leave for others to downvote. There are many trust me (*￣m￣)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Please give me some advice so that I can avoid this nonsense and concentrate on helping other people

Sure: ignore the downvotes. Move on.

Those downvotes won't have any real consequence since you have tons of upvotes to "counter" them. And if done serially, the downvotes will be reversed automatically anyway.

Comment: thanks I will stick to your advice. I will do the same